# Why AWS Sagemaker Studio domain is hanging and showing 'Unknown user'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I'm trying to launch a SageMaker studio domain within VPC, but it's hanging all the time. if i check the app status inside my user profile, it shows me 'ready', but the studio interface keeps showing me the logo, also it keeps showing me the text box below:
[image]

after waiting for more than 30mins, I can finally see the studio interface, but on the right top it's showing me `Unknown User`, and it couldn't let me create a new notebook etc. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Do you have an STS endpoint set up for the VPC? You can also check in the browser console log if there are any timeout errors.

Comment: @durga_sury i do see a networking error when launching the studio, which I have updated in my question, but still not sure what it's trying to indicate...

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Not sure if that affects the UI. Does your VPC have an S3 endpoint? I wonder if it's not able to reach S3 (for Jumpstart) or STS (to get the caller identity to show on your UI).

Comment: @durga_sury i'm in contact with AWS support now, seems like a tricky one

Comment: Can you check if your security groups are configured properly? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-notebooks-and-internet-access.html talks about the required rules. If you were able to resolve, can you answer this question for future users?

Comment: @durga_sury the issue seems to be resolved by itself. AWS said it might be caused by some upstreaming networking issue which is not controlled by them or my side...